# Reusing Runnable for handler.postDelayed()

Tags: android, runnable, postdelayed

I am trying to avoid garbage creation by reusing runnable. However, I am stuck on how to implement this correctly.

Here is my runnable wrapper class:

```
    public class RotateRunnable implements Runnable {

    Maze maze;
    int i;
    int steps;
    int originalAngle;
    int dir;

    public RotateRunnable(Maze maze) {
        this.maze = maze;
    }

    public void setRunnable(int i, int steps, int originalAngle, int dir) {
        this.i = i;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.originalAngle = originalAngle;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        maze.setIsRotateRunning(true);
        maze.setAngle(originalAngle + dir*(90*(i+1))/steps);
        maze.rotateStep();
    }

}
```

And here is where I have implemented it:

```
    private void smoothAnimateRotate(final int i, final int steps, final int originalAngle, final int dir) {
//      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
//              isRotateRunning = true;
//              angle = originalAngle + dir*(90*(i+1))/steps;
//              rotateStep();
//          }
//      }, 25 * (i));
        rotateRunnable.setRunnable(i, steps, originalAngle, dir);
        handler.postDelayed(rotateRunnable, 25 * i);
    }
```

The commented out section is working code. The problem I am running into is setting the variables inside `rotateRunnable` before `postDelay()` is called. Right now that is not working as `rotateRunnable` is likely only executing the last variables that are set. This is because `smoothAnimateRotate()` is executed inside a for-loop which updates the variables very quickly.

How do I make setting the variables part of the `run` method so that when `run` is executed later, it is executing with the correctly set variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, call handler.postDelayed method is actually push a message into the MessageQueue,and set the message's callback with your runnable object. From your description, you called smoothAnimateRotate method inside a for-loop very quickly, this may only take a very short time , even less than 25ms, so when messageQueue start poll messages and excute rotateRunnable,only executing the last variables that are set.

you can allocate a ArrayList object to cache all the variables like below

```
public class RotateRunnable implements Runnable {

public static int index = 0;
public static ArrayList<RotateNode> rotateNodeList = new ArrayList<RotateNode>();

Maze maze;
int i;
int steps;
int originalAngle;
int dir;

public RotateRunnable(Maze maze) {
    this.maze = maze;
}

public void setRunnable(int i, int steps, int originalAngle, int dir) {
    RotateNode node = new RotateNode();
    node.i = i % 100;
    node.steps = steps;
    node.originalAngle = originalAngle;
    node.dir = dir;
    rotateNodeList.add(i % 100, node);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    RotateNode node = rotateNodeList.get(index % 100);
    maze.setIsRotateRunning(true);
    maze.setAngle(node.originalAngle + node.dir*(90*(node.i+1))/node.steps);
    maze.rotateStep();
    index ++;

}
```

}

```
public class RotateNode {
int i;
int steps;
int originalAngle;
int dir;
```

}

to avoid arraylist's size infinite increace, i assume the rotate animation is 100 steps per circle, you can replace it with your steps per circle.Hope this works for you.